# Puppet elasticsearch module (class vs define)

Tags: elasticsearch, puppet, hiera

I am trying to use the following [elasticsearch](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch) module for puppet (with hiera).

I am trying to configure the `node.name` for example, which can be seen in the `instance.pp` file.

`elasticsearch::instance` is not a class however, it is only defined and it seems to be used in the other classes (specifically elasticsearch, in `init.pp`).

I have tried instantiating it as a class, as well as config through something like:

`elasticsearch::elasticsearch::instance::node.name: 'myname'` in my .yaml, but to no avail.

Comment: Please specify your question, because right now it hard for me to understand what is the real problem. You want to know the difference between class and define in puppet / You want to know how to instance `elasticsearch::instance` or maybe how to create such instance with hiera ?

Answer (score 3):

I will try to explain all problems you mentioned.

1. [Class](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_classes.html#language:-classes) vs [define](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/4.1/reference/lang_defined_types.html#language:-defined-resource-types). The main difference is that classes are singletons in puppet.
2. If you want to create an instance of `elasticsearch::instance`
   just add to your puppet manifest:

`elasticsearch::instance { 'some_name': }`

exactly the same as in [examples](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch#instances).

3. The purpose of using [hiera](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/) with puppet is to provide proper values to puppet manifests depend on deployment environment. You cannot create a resource just by defining it in hiera. If you define some resource in hiera, use [create_resource](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/function.html#createresources) function to create an instance. 
   Please read the following [article](http://garylarizza.com/blog/2014/10/24/puppet-workflows-4-using-hiera-in-anger/). As in example, the equivalent of making an instance in puppet manifest:

   ```
   users { 'gary':
     ensure   => present,
     uid      => '5001',
     gid      => 'gary',
     shell    => 'zsh',
     password => $password,
   }
   ```

is, the following definition in hiera

```
#some.yaml
users:
  gary:
    ensure: 'present'
    uid: '5001'
    gid: 'gary'
    shell: 'zsh'
    password: 'biglongpasswordhash'
```

with instantiation in puppet manifest:

```
$users = hiera('users')
create_resources('users')
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description, seems you understand the difference between `class` and `define`. To answer your question directly, it should be organised as:

```
---
elasticsearch::instances:
  es-01:
    config:
      node.name: 'es-01'
  es-02:
    config:
      node.name: 'es-02'
```

[multipleinstances.yaml](https://github.com/elastic/puppet-elasticsearch/blob/ba8c255736fffc494afa2ac1e9cedfddad09dc66/spec/fixtures/hiera/hieradata/multipleinstances.yaml)